# Flex Repeater: Delay repeater until rest of view has loaded

Tags: apache-flex, repeater

I have a flex repeater for an accordion inside a TitleWindow that is quite slow, I've already set recycleChildren to true, which has helped, but it's still slow on the first load and causes the animation to stutter when I open the TitleWindow.

The repeater is just one part of what's visible in the TitleWindow, what I would like to do is have the repeater load after the rest of the content in the TitleWindow so the animation of the TitleWindow being opened doesn't stutter (the main problem).

Can anyone suggest what the best way to achieve that might be?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can create a state and put the repeater in the state. Change to this state in the creationComplete event of the titleWindow.